# What kind of chemicals would exist at the heat death of the universe?

Tags: enthalpy, stability, entropy

As the universe reaches the maximum entropy, presumably only the most stable chemicals would exist.

Assume that all the elements haven't turn into iron yet, what kind of chemicals would dominate at that point?

Comment: [A Dying Universe: The Long Term Fate and Evolution of Astrophysical Objects](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9701131) Section V.F.3 looks at Positronium (and lots of neat things before that) mentioned by Nicolau's answer.

Answer (score 10):

There is a lot of uncertainty regarding the far future of our Universe, but it seems that chemistry as we know it will be gone long before the end. Both free and bound protons (and neutrons) are <strike>expected</strike> predicted to decay through at least one of several mechanisms, with a half-life [somewhere between the range of $10^{35}$-$10^{200}$ yr](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9701131) (far shorter than the timescale for nuclear reactions to convert all matter into iron, [~$10^{1500}$ yr](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.447)). Therefore, at some point the statistically expected number of atoms inside our observable bubble could potentially dip below 1.

Should proton decay happen relatively quickly, perhaps the last elements in the Universe will be present near the end of the black hole era (~$10^{100}$ yr), when the last supermassive black holes decay in a flash of subatomic particles, possibly creating small amounts of new protons/neutrons. These will decay in a comparative blink of an eye at this timescale, however, and the Universe will soon become a barren place once more.

The last structures with any semblance to matter in the Universe will likely be [positronium "atoms"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium), where an electron and a positron (anti-electron) orbit each other in a pseudo-hydrogen atom. Though ground-state positronium decays in a matter of nanoseconds or less, it will be very long-lived in the future due to the extreme sparsity of subatomic particles in the hugely expanded observable bubble, with a mean distance between a bound positron and electron measured in <strike>trillions of trillions of trillions of trillions of...</strike> billions of lightyears or more. Even in these conditions, positronium too shall eventually decay, in a timescale of anywhere between ~$10^{140}$ yr and ~$10^{800}$ yr.

Before all of these nuclear processes take place, there may also be a significant amount of unusual chemical reactions happening solely due to tunnelling effects, even at arbitrarily low temperatures, since the kinetic barriers for chemical reactions are far smaller than that for nuclear reactions. For example, most molecules containing nitrogen atoms are thermodynamically unstable with respect to release of $\ce{N2}$, and so might spontaneously break up even at $\mathrm{0\ K}$ given enough time. I don't know what the timescale for these processes is, however.

Comment: Slight nitpick: I wouldn't say protons are _expected_ to decay. Some GUTs predict that they should decay, but there's no evidence for those theories yet. There's no _experimental_ result that provides any support for proton decay being real, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Trillions of light years between electron and positron? Given that coulomb force decreases with the square of the distance there wouldn't be much force to attract them.

Comment: @DavidZ Indeed proton decay by GUT mechanisms may not exist, but that does not rule out all forms of proton decay. The article in my first link devotes a fair amount of attention to several mechanisms, including one which seems to involve no extension to the Standard Model (as far as I'm aware, I could well be wrong!).

Comment: From the article: "To summarize this discussion, we stress that many different mechanisms for baryon number violation and proton decay can be realized within modern theories of particle physics. As a result, it seems likely that the proton must eventually decay with a lifetime somewhere in the range [$10^{32}$-$10^{200}$ yr]".

Comment: @user137 Yes, the attraction between electron and positron will be extremely small, but still non-zero. Given there's almost nothing else around, the attraction will stand above the noise even at such gigantic separations. The positronium atom can be thought of as a [Rydberg atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom) with an exceptionally high principal quantum number $n$. From the first article: "At the time of formation, the positronium atoms are generally in states of very high quantum number (and have radii larger than the current horizon size [~$10^{11}$ ly]).

Comment: Sure, I didn't mean to imply that GUTs are the only mechanism for proton decay. I missed that the article considers some others. Still, all of them involve BSM physics; the standard model conserves baryon number, so the proton, as the lightest baryon, is necessarily stable in that model. Honestly, I think their statement "it seems likely that the proton must eventually decay" without further qualification is simply not justified.

Answer (score 0):

As a semi-literate in these matters, it seems to me that, logically at heat death, there can only be low temperature photons, as any matter would represent a local concentration of energy.

Comment: This is very short, and whilst correct (I think, I'm not an expert) it would be more appropriate as a comment unless you want to expand on it significantly, which would be very interesting so I encourage you to do that.

Comment: "Logically" is perhaps a dangerous word to use in this situation, as there is a lot of difficult, deep and entirely unintuitive physics involved. For example, [Freeman Dyson points out](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.447) that without assuming proton decay, the matter remnants of the Universe will depend on the minimum mass of a black hole, which is the domain of quantum gravity, at the very edge of contemporary physics. It may be possible that nuclear matter could be infinitely stable so long as present in the form of small grains, of size $\mathrm{<100\ \mu m}$.